# How to load specific files for different countries in Android

Tags: android, parsing, android-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change language programatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)

I would like to develop an Android app which will offer some specific information based on the user selection of a country. So the user will choose a country and the app will update the fields for that country. The information is text.
For each country the information would be about 2-3 pages, with different main fields.

My first thought was to add text files to the application in the "res/raw" folder and load them after getting the user preference. Is that the best way to do it?  Another idea would be to add xml files in res/xml ( it would be easier to parse? ).

And if I would go with prepackaged text files, which would be the best way to parse the text file for adding information in the specific fields of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is good to put them in "`res/raw`". You may consider using `xml` files instead of plain text files. It could be easier to parse and better organized.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommend to use the method from Jave, but your way is also possible.
Create for every language element in /res/values/strings.xml. You can set and select the chosen language with shared preferences. The file to select the chosen language is something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) getViewById(R.id.textviewid);

SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
boolean language = getPrefs.getString("language", "en");
if(language == "en") tv.setText(this.getString(R.string.en));
if(language == "nl") tv.setText(this.getString(R.string.nl));
if(language == "de") tv.setText(this.getString(R.string.de));
```

You have to make a layout for the page to choose a language by yourself. The java to set the language preference is something like this. I've used a textview to keep it simple, but it's recommend to change it to a dropdown menu orso. And you have to put this on a place where it checks it after clicking a button orso.

```
EditText lang = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etId);

SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
Editor editor = someData.edit();
editor.putString("language", lang.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

I haven't tested anything, so it can contain errors. If it does show errors and you don't know how to fix it I would like to help you.

*I'm sorry for my bad English*

//EDIT:
The strings.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <string name="en">Hello! This is the text!</string>
    <string name="nl">Hallo! Dit is de tekst!</string>
    ....
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really what you are looking for, but you might be interested in reading the developer document about [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) as well.

Comment: I read about that but that is to support different languages. I want to give information which is specific to different countries, not necessarily the country the user is in.

Comment: That's what I thought. But I figured it could be related anyway, especially for the people coming here after reading the title of the question :)